# Ormlite: FieldType is a primitive type but marked as foreign

Tags: android, ormlite

I'd like to know, what does the error from title mean - it occurs very often in my project but it makes absolutely no sens (obviously, related classes are nerver primitive types).

It appears to me that this error is thrown if some relations are misconfigured (like misspelled foreign field name in annotation) - but the error gives no information about it. Finding those wrong relations is so time consuming that I could have spent this time on writing my model in plain sql without any orm!

I've also hit a strange situation in which I see nothing wrong - but the "primitive type marked as foreign" exception is thrown again. Below's this situation.

Along many tables in model (about 50 classes) I create these two:
Tab1:

```
@DatabaseTable()
public class Tab1 {
    @DatabaseField(generatedId = true)
    int id;

    @ForeignCollectionField(eager = false, foreignFieldName = "tab1")
    Collection<Tab2> tab2;

    public Tab1() {
    }

    public int getId() {
            return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
            this.id = id;
    }

    public Collection<Tab2> getTab2() {
            return tab2;
    }
}
```

Tab2:

```
@DatabaseTable()
public class Tab2 {
    @DatabaseField(generatedId = true)
    int id;

    @DatabaseField(foreign = true)
    Tab1 tab1;

    public Tab2() {
    }

    public Tab2(Tab1 tab1) {
            super();
            this.tab1 = tab1;
    }

    public int getId() {
            return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
            this.id = id;
    }

    public Tab1 getTab1() {
            return tab1;
    }

    public void setTab1(Tab1 tab1) {
            this.tab1 = tab1;
    }
}
```

In DatabaseHelper I create daos:

```
public class DatabaseHelper extends OrmLiteSqliteOpenHelper {

    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "samplename.db";
    private static final String BACKUP_DATABASE_NAME = "samplename_bak.db";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 2;
    private static String DB_PATH = "/data/data/com.samplepath/databases/";

// DAOs

Dao<Tab1, Integer> tab1Dao;
Dao<Tab2, Integer> tab2Dao;
    // many other daos

    public Dao<Tab1, Integer> getTab1Dao() {
            try {
                    if (tab1Dao == null) {
                            tab1Dao = DaoManager.createDao(connectionSource, Tab1.class);
                    }
                    return tab1Dao;
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                    return null;
            }
    }

    public Dao<Tab2, Integer> getTab2Dao() {
            try {
                    if (tab2Dao == null) {
                            tab2Dao = DaoManager.createDao(connectionSource, Tab2.class);
                    }
                    return tab2Dao;
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                    return null;
            }
    }
    //many other dao getters

    public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
            super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION, R.raw.ormlite_config);
            Log.i("dbTag", "Creating database from file...");
            SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase, ConnectionSource connectionSource) {
            try {
                    Log.i("dbTag", "Creating database....");
                    TableUtils.createTable(connectionSource, Tab1.class);
                    TableUtils.createTable(connectionSource, Tab2.class);
                    //other create tables
                    Log.i("Exception", "inserted");
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                    Log.i("Exception", "error - could not create database.");
                    Log.i("Exception", e.getMessage());
                    Log.e("Exception", "", e);
            }
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase, ConnectionSource connectionSource, int oldVersion,
                    int newVersion) {
            try {
                    Log.i("dbTag", "onUpgrade");
                    Log.i("dbTag", "Dropping database....");
                    TableUtils.dropTable(connectionSource, Tab1.class, true);
                    TableUtils.dropTable(connectionSource, Tab2.class, true);
                    //other drops
                    Log.i("dbTag", "Creating database....");
                    onCreate(sqLiteDatabase, connectionSource);
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                    Log.e(DatabaseHelper.class.getName(), "Can't drop databases", e);
                    throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
    }
}
```

I also include this two classes in config util and create the ormlite_config.txt file.
I manage the database helper in base activity along with roboguice:

```
public class BaseActivity<T extends OrmLiteSqliteOpenHelper, E extends BaseErrorHandler> extends OrmLiteBaseActivity<T> implements RoboContext, IErrorHandler {

    protected EventManager eventManager;
    protected HashMap<Key<?>,Object> scopedObjects = new HashMap<Key<?>,Object>();
    protected E errorHandler;
    public static final DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    public static Map<String,String> args = null;

    @Inject
    ContentViewListener ignored; // do not use?

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        final RoboInjector injector = RoboGuice.getInjector(this);
        eventManager = injector.getInstance(EventManager.class);
        injector.injectMembersWithoutViews(this);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        eventManager.fire(new OnCreateEvent(savedInstanceState));
    }

    @Override
    protected void onRestart() {
        super.onRestart();
        eventManager.fire(new OnRestartEvent());
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        eventManager.fire(new OnStartEvent());
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        eventManager.fire(new OnResumeEvent());
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        eventManager.fire(new OnPauseEvent());
    }

    @Override
    protected void onNewIntent( Intent intent ) {
        super.onNewIntent(intent);
        eventManager.fire(new OnNewIntentEvent());
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        try {
            eventManager.fire(new OnStopEvent());
        } finally {
            super.onStop();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        try {
            eventManager.fire(new OnDestroyEvent());
        } finally {
            try {
                RoboGuice.destroyInjector(this);
            } finally {
                super.onDestroy();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        final Configuration currentConfig = getResources().getConfiguration();
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        eventManager.fire(new OnConfigurationChangedEvent(currentConfig, newConfig));
    }

    @Override
    public void onContentChanged() {
        super.onContentChanged();
        RoboGuice.getInjector(this).injectViewMembers(this);
        eventManager.fire(new OnContentChangedEvent());
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        eventManager.fire(new OnActivityResultEvent(requestCode, resultCode, data));
    }

    public Map<Key<?>, Object> getScopedObjectMap() {
        return scopedObjects;
    }

    @Override
    public void handleError(int resId) {
        errorHandler.exceptionHandler(getString(resId), this);
    }

}
```

In the lunching activity I run code:

```
Log.i("Tab1", "creating tab1");
getHelper().getTab1Dao();
Log.i("Tab1", "created tab1");
Log.i("Tab1", "creating tab2");
getHelper().getTab2Dao();
Log.i("Tab1", "created tab2");
```

The app is firstly uninstalled from device and then installed and run again. This is what I see in the logs:

```
03-14 11:22:54.400: I/DaoManager(31657): Loaded configuration for class com.xxx.xxx.model.Tab1
03-14 11:22:54.400: I/DaoManager(31657): Loaded configuration for class com.xxx.xxx.model.Tab2
03-14 11:22:54.423: I/dbTag(31657): Creating database from file...
03-14 11:22:54.486: I/dbTag(31657): Creating database....
03-14 11:22:54.494: I/TableUtils(31657): creating table 'tab1'
03-14 11:22:54.494: I/TableUtils(31657): executed create table statement changed 1 rows: CREATE TABLE `tab1` (`id` INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT ) 
03-14 11:22:54.494: I/TableUtils(31657): creating table 'tab2'
03-14 11:22:54.501: I/TableUtils(31657): executed create table statement changed 1 rows: CREATE TABLE `tab2` (`id` INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT , `tab1_id` INTEGER ) 
[...]
03-14 11:22:55.283: I/Tab1(31657): creating tab1
03-14 11:22:55.291: E/Tab1(31657): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Field FieldType:name=tab1,class=Tab2 is a primitive class class com.xxx.xxx.model.Tab1 but marked as foreign
03-14 11:22:55.291: E/Tab1(31657):  at com.j256.ormlite.field.FieldType.configDaoInformation(FieldType.java:315)
03-14 11:22:55.291: E/Tab1(31657):  at com.j256.ormlite.dao.BaseDaoImpl.initialize(BaseDaoImpl.java:200)
03-14 11:22:55.291: E/Tab1(31657):  at com.j256.ormlite.dao.BaseDaoImpl.<init>(BaseDaoImpl.java:126)
03-14 11:22:55.291: E/Tab1(31657):  at com.j256.ormlite.dao.BaseDaoImpl.<init>(BaseDaoImpl.java:117)
03-14 11:22:55.291: E/Tab1(31657):  at com.j256.ormlite.dao.BaseDaoImpl$5.<init>(BaseDaoImpl.java:911)
03-14 11:22:55.291: E/Tab1(31657):  at com.j256.ormlite.dao.BaseDaoImpl.createDao(BaseDaoImpl.java:911)
03-14 11:22:55.291: E/Tab1(31657):  at com.j256.ormlite.dao.DaoManager.doCreateDao(DaoManager.java:359)
03-14 11:22:55.291: E/Tab1(31657):  at com.j256.ormlite.dao.DaoManager.createDaoFromConfig(DaoManager.java:326)
03-14 11:22:55.291: E/Tab1(31657):  at com.j256.ormlite.dao.DaoManager.createDao(DaoManager.java:55)
03-14 11:22:55.291: E/Tab1(31657):  at com.j256.ormlite.android.apptools.OrmLiteSqliteOpenHelper.getDao(OrmLiteSqliteOpenHelper.java:239)
03-14 11:22:55.291: E/Tab1(31657):  at com.xxx.xxx.xxx.onCreate(XXX.java:43)
03-14 11:22:55.291: E/Tab1(31657):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
03-14 11:22:55.291: E/Tab1(31657):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1053)
03-14 11:22:55.291: E/Tab1(31657):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1934)
03-14 11:22:55.291: E/Tab1(31657):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1995)
03-14 11:22:55.291: E/Tab1(31657):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:128)
03-14 11:22:55.291: E/Tab1(31657):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1161)
03-14 11:22:55.291: E/Tab1(31657):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-14 11:22:55.291: E/Tab1(31657):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-14 11:22:55.291: E/Tab1(31657):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4514)
03-14 11:22:55.291: E/Tab1(31657):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-14 11:22:55.291: E/Tab1(31657):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
03-14 11:22:55.291: E/Tab1(31657):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:790)
03-14 11:22:55.291: E/Tab1(31657):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:557)
03-14 11:22:55.291: E/Tab1(31657):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Furthermore, I have custom daos for all other classes in model but I don't use them for this two classes. I also have interface for every other class in model (I know this is weird, but I must have it for some purposes).

Any help will be greatly appreciated, thank you!

Comment: I don't know the answer but when I've had similar problems, setting a breakpoint within the ormlite source code (FieldType.java in this case) helped me understand what it was trying to do. At least it should let you see which fields it is looking at and what it how it thinks they are declared.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In case anybody hits similar problem: don't call this.getWritableDatabase() in constructor of DatabaseHelper. When I removed this, the code magically started to work - no idea, why it happened, but it works.

Answer (score 1):

Huh.  Well the error was *supposed* to be self explanatory

```
Field FieldType:name=tab1,class=Tab2 is a primitive class 
    class com.xxx.xxx.model.Tab1 but marked as foreign
```

For some reason the `Tab2` type has the `tab1` field marked as being a primitive class.  In you class, however, the `tab1` field is defined as:

```
@DatabaseField(foreign = true)
Tab1 tab1;
```

Is there any chance that you have not updated your database config file associated with this class?  Maybe it *used* to be an `int` and now it is a `Tab1`?  You will need to regenerate your config file when you change you schema.

Comment: The config file is updated for sure. These two tables were just a test cases added to existing code. The tab1 field was always of type Tab1. However when I've added these classes to an empty project they worked correctly. I think this may be connected with eather interface added to all classes in model (these two don't implement it, but maybe the orm is confused because of this interface anyway) or with broken relation in some other class which leads the orm to break. Also, when I create the dao, catch Exception and create it again - it's created correctly.

Comment: Sorry @matt112358.  No idea.

Answer (score 0):

I come across the same problem , though I don't know what exactly the problem is , but I'm sure it's caused by the ormlite_config.txt file. Once I delete the file, and change the database helper class's constructor to not use the ormlite_config.txt version. everything just works fine.